# Storybook Angualr and ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I want to create stories for angular components that use ng-bootstrap. However when i make these stories for example for this example code ( all component are working only storybook gives the errors)

```
<div id="{{collapseName}}" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
```

i get the following error.

> Can't bind to 'ngbCollapse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

How do I make a basic story that supports this

Comment: can you create stackblitz reproducing the error

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, `ngbCollapse` is not a property of `div`, it's a directive included in `NgbModule`. You have to import that module to be able to use it in your application. If you want to use the directives from `NgbModule` in different components, you could import and export `NgbModule` in your `SharedModule`, and then import `SharedModule` in all your modules.

I would recommend taking a look at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started